# Python - Seperate letters in a list

Tags: python

Code:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
words = []

for letter in a:
  if letter == "\n":
    word.append(a[0:a.index(letter)])
    del a[0:a.index(letter)+1]
    print(a)

print(words)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
['d', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
['g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

I wanted the final words list to be `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]`. Why does not append the last item?

Comment: Shorter: `words = [list(line) for line in ''.join(a).rstrip('\n').splitlines()]`

Comment: Replace `for letter in a:` with `for (i, letter) in enumerate(a):`, and insert `print(i, letter)` right before the `if`. You will probably realize what's happening. If not, call me :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 iterations instead of 12 because you are mutating the list during the loop.

```
words = []
a = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', '\n',
  'd', 'e', 'f', '\n',
  'g', 'h', 'i', '\n'
]

for i, letter in enumerate(a) :
  print(a, "\n", (
    # padding to shift i to the right
    ' ' * (len(str(a[0:i])) + (i and 2))
  ), i, sep = "")
  if letter == "\n" :
    words.append(a[0:a.index(letter)])
    del a[0:a.index(letter)+1]
    print(
      "# '\\n' found at", i,
      "=> words +=", words[-1],
      '\n'
    )

print(words)
```

As you can see below, there is nothing to loop through after `i = 7` because `len(a) = 8`.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
  0
['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
       1
['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
            2
['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
                 3
# '\n' found at 3 => words += ['a', 'b', 'c']

['d', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
                       4
['d', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
                            5
['d', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
                                 6
['d', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
                                      7
# '\n' found at 7 => words += ['d', 'e', 'f']

[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

One possible fix is to stop mutating the list (this is what most people do).

```
words = []
a = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', '\n',
  'd', 'e', 'f', '\n',
  'g', 'h', 'i', '\n'
]

for i, letter in enumerate(a) :
  if letter == "\n" :
    words.append(a[i-3:i])

print(words)
```

Or you can replace `for` with `while`.

```
words = []
a = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', '\n',
  'd', 'e', 'f', '\n',
  'g', 'h', 'i', '\n'
]

while a != [] :
  words.append(a[0:a.index('\n')])
  del a[0:a.index('\n')+1]

print(words)
```

If you don't understand, drop a comment :-)

Answer (score -1):

A solution to have the final list you want:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
words = []
group = []

for letter in a:
    if letter == "\n":
        words.append(group)
        group = []
    else:
        group.append(letter)

print(words)
```

output is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Each one element in list is letter, then

```py
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\n', 'g', 'h', 'i', '\n']
>>> list(map(list, ''.join(a).split()))
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```